# NSDate 'isEqualToString' crash?

Tags: ios, crash, nsdate

So this is by far the weirdest crash I have seen yet. This is the crash:
Code:

```
2011-08-21 21:04:39.321 App[548:707] -[__NSDate isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1227d0
2011-08-21 21:04:39.332 App[548:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1227d0'
```

This crash happens when I go from one view to another. The weird thing is I do a search in my view controller I am going to for 'isEqualToString' ***and nothing comes up***, which is crazy  . So then I do a search for NSDate and the only thing that comes up is this:
Code:

```
if(sortbar.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        NSComparator sortByDate = ^(id dict1, id dict2) {
            NSDate* n1 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"Date"];
            NSDate* n2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"Date"];
            return (NSComparisonResult)[n1 compare:n2];
        };
        [self.cellArray sortUsingComparator:sortByDate];
    }
```

I doubt that code is causing the crash but I really need help with this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Add a symbolic breakpoint for exceptions and see where it breaks. http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/03/19/break-on-exception-in-xcode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your dictionary is returning a string instead of an NSDate.